# Retrieving barcode scan results via python

Tags: python-2.7, barcode-scanner

I am looking for a way to scan a barcode and retrieve the result from the barcode scanner via python.

However, the problem lies with the barcode scanner acting like a keyboard, writing whatever was scanned to the currently open program. This is a problem because I only want the scanned data to be handled by the python program, and not pasted on-screen in whatever program in currently open.

I have tried using the following code:

```
ean = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
```

Which completes the requirement of it being handled in the python program. Nevertheless, it fails in not pasting it on-screen.

My question is if it is at all possible for python to process the scanned data internally in the program, but not let it show up anywhere else, ie. not letting the scanner act as a keyboard. Or is this rather the setting of the scanner that I might have to change ?